# Is value of bInterfaceProtocol fixed or decided by Kernel?

Tags: usb, usb-device, interface, protocols, lsusb

Let's say:

```
$ ls -l /dev/input/by-id
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 10 03:47 usb-Logitech_USB_Keyboard-event-if01 -> ../event22
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 10 03:47 usb-Logitech_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd -> ../event21
$ ls -l /dev/input/by-path/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 10 03:47 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1.1:1.0-event-kbd -> ../event21
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 10 03:47 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1.1:1.1-event -> ../event22
```

I know Interface number 1 (event22) above is non-functional because of `bInterfaceProtocol` is `None` for `bInterfaceNumber 1`:

```
$ sudo lsusb -v -d 046d:c31c

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x046d Logitech, Inc.
  idProduct          0xc31c Keyboard K120
  bcdDevice           64.00
  iManufacturer           1 Logitech
  iProduct                2 USB Keyboard
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           59
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          3 U64.00_B0001
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               90mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              2 USB Keyboard
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      65
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              2 USB Keyboard
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     159
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval             255
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
$
```

I don't get it and raise up two possibility questions:

1. If value of `bInterfaceProtocol` always `None` independent of Host, then what's the point of this unused Interface exists ?
2. If value of `bInterfaceProtocol` decided by Kernel, then what's
   the condition did Kernel take to set it to None ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel does not decide the `bInterfaceProtocol`. The value is received from the connected USB device.

> A variety of protocols are supported HID devices. The bInterfaceProtocol
>   member of an Interface descriptor only has meaning if the bInterfaceSubClass
>   member declares that the device supports a boot interface, otherwise it is 0.

Check [USB Device Class Definition for HID 1.11](https://www.usb.org/document-library/device-class-definition-hid-111) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Besides of [@desowin answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518548/64403), I want to add that the devices which has multiple interfaces means it's a composite device, as stated at [An Introduction to Universal Serial Bus 2.0](https://www.cypress.com/file/134171/download):

> At the same time, a device can have multiple interfaces, thus multiple
>   interface descriptors. A USB device with multiple interfaces that
>   perform different functions is called a composite device. An example
>   is a USB audio head set. In the head set, you have a single USB device
>   with two interfaces. One interface is for the audio side of the
>   headset and another interface may be the controls to adjust the
>   volume. Multiple interfaces can be active at the same time.

To figure out what's the functionality of this `None` device interface, I tested with `sudo cat /dev/input/by-id/usb-CHESEN_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd` and `sudo cat /dev/input/by-id/usb-CHESEN_USB_Keyboard-event-if01` while pressing different keys, and eventually I noticed only `if01` will get output when I pressing Multimedia keys to open Bluetooth settings and adjust volume.